# Proxy URL doesn't work on angular js controller

Tags: angularjs, express, http-proxy

I'm working on an app using **expressjs** and **angularjs**.

I create my backend using [express generator](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html) install some tools like mysql, body parser and cors.

On my frontend, I am using gulp together with angularjs.

**This is my controller**

```
    app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method : "GET",
        url : "http://localhost:4007/users"
    }).then(function mySuccess(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.data;
    }, function myError(response) {
        $scope.myWelcome = response.statusText;
    });
});
```

**App.js**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();


// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

var mysql = require("mysql");

app.use(function(req, res, next){ 
  res.locals.connection = mysql.createConnection({ 
    host : 'localhost', 
    user : 'root', 
    password : '', 
    database : 'test'
  }); 
  res.locals.connection.connect(); 
  next(); 
});

// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

const cors = require('cors')

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204 
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});


var http = require('http');
module.exports = app;
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(4007);
```

**route/users.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.locals.connection.query('SELECT * from users', function (error, results, fields) {
   if(error) throw error;
   res.send(JSON.stringify(results));
 });
});
```

Actually the code works fine, I can send and get request from the backend.

what I'm trying to achieved is how can I remove the `http://localhost:4007` and just use the `/users` upon requesting and sending data to the api.

I tried to add `"proxy": "http://localhost:4007"` on package.json at my frontend but didn't work.

I found the idea [here](https://blog.cloudboost.io/react-express-the-nodejs-way-of-reacting-and-expressing-7a518e4da3).

Hope you help me.

Comment: is your app served by express? what boilerplate are you using.? 
this can be achieved by setting a proxy server on express js. what you have seen in a feature that `create-react-app` provides. if you have express as dev server i can help in setting it up

Comment: @hannadrehman thank you sir, yes I use express. how can I contact you?

Comment: for starters.  update your question and state what all are u using like dev server, project boilerplate, backend server, how is front end being served and if there is any build configuration

Comment: @hannadrehman kindly check its updated

Comment: what about your front end server ? proxy will be added to front end server. can you share that code. i mean `localhost:3000`

Comment: @hannadrehman I dont have that sir, its automatic when I put the backend port to the controller.

Comment: your front end should also be running on some server ? during your development, you could be using some server to server your JS and html files ?

Comment: @hannadrehman, well I use gulp to make copies from node_modules to my src files. and run `gulp` start the app, this is the tutorial I followed to make my frontend https://coursetro.com/posts/design/72/Installing-Bootstrap-4-Tutorial

Comment: now we are talking !!!. give me some time, i will post the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `gulp` and `browser-sync` as your build tool and dev server. from [this](https://coursetro.com/posts/design/72/Installing-Bootstrap-4-Tutorial) tutorial. the proxy will be done on the dev server only.

a proxy will simply redirect all your trafic to different server.  ex `/api/user` => `localhost:4007/api/user`.

install `http-proxy-middleware` by `npm i -D http-proxy-middleware`

update your `gulp` like this.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var sass        = require('gulp-sass');

var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

var proxy = proxyMiddleware('/user', {target: 'localhost:4007/users'});

gulp.task('serve', ['sass'], function() {

browserSync.init({
    server: "./src" ,
    middleware: [proxy] 
});
```

here `/users` will be proxied to `localhost:4006/users`
this is actually not a good practice to do. instead you should target a pattern
of urls  ex.

```
var proxy = proxyMiddleware('/api/*', {target: 'localhost:4007'});
```

this would proxy all urls that match this pattern like
`api/users/`
`api/auth/me`
`api/profile/extra`

Comment: I tried it sir, but didn't work, maybe I missed something